# Excel Array Formula and combination

Tags: arrays, excel

Need to get data based on the results returned by array formula

[image]

Now I need to get:

- Find highest of Column(D) where Column(C)=1. "Value->1868". (i.e between 16:00-18:00 Hrs,highest for 1)
- From the same row of above result, get the column values for Column(G)->1256 and (H)->57

To get the first - highest of Column(D), I have the following Array formula which works fine.
=MAX(IF((C10:C30)=1,D10:D30))

Now based on this, how do I get the highest of Col-G and H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX/MATCH` to do that, e.g. for column G value try this "array formula"

`=INDEX(G10:G30,MATCH(1,(D10:D30=MAX(IF(C10:C30=1,D10:D30)))*(C10:C30=1),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

replace `G10:G30` with `H10:H30` to gt the column H value

of course if you already have your formula in B31 you can use that result in my suggested formula to simplify, i.e.

`=INDEX(G10:G30,MATCH(1,(D10:D30=B31)*(C10:C30=1),0))`

Comment: Wow...works Great. Thank you... Will dig-in later how this works!

Comment: I'm little confused why/how the *(C10:C30=1) being used. Could you pls explain?

Comment: I assumed you might have duplicate values in D10:D30 (e.g. 1868 could occur more than once and maybe on rows where C10:C30 = 2), so you need to look for rows where 2 conditions are satisfied, i.e. D10:D30=B31 and also C10:C30=1 when you test those you get arrays of either TRUE or FALSE and when you multiply those arrays only TRUE*TRUE = 1 so MATCH looks for a 1 which equates to the first row where both conditions are met....and INDEX returns the corresponding row from G10:G30